# c# - Creating a method that uses an array AND restarting a console application with a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, methods

My most humble greetings S.O folk,

I am having trouble with the syntax and language requirements for the following assessment criteria.

NOTE: I am not looking for a definitive/"here you go!" answer (i.e: a completed assignment) but I do genuinely need some guidance with the c# language in order to complete the assignment. Thank you in advance.

This is the assignment brief:

1. Generate a card for the dealer that displays 2 random numbers using a struct.
2. Generate a card for the player that displays 3 random numbers using (the same) struct.

-- So far, I have been able to do this with the code at the bottom of my post. The rest of the assessment criteria has me stuck --

1. Ask the user to type in which single number they want to "play" against the dealer to win. These options should be stored in an array {0, 1, 2} that will be called upon to run a method to calculate the winner. I must also use the TryParse method(?) to convert the user input into a number. -- To run the calculate winner method, I am assuming that I will use an if statement something like this:

   ```
   if (PlayerSelection > DealerCard) 
   { 
       Console.WriteLine ("You Win");
   }
   else (DealerCard > PlayerSelection) 
   { 
       Console.WriteLine ("Dealer Wins");
   }
   else if (PlayerSelection == DealerCard)
   { 
       Console.WriteLine ("It is a draw");
   }
   ```

-- Apart from the above, I do not understand the syntax for using the tryParse method to convert user input into a number--

1. Finally, I must create a loop that will run the program again depending on user input. Would you like to play again? User input Yes = run application again  or User input No = Exit application.

As I said, this is an assignment so I'm not looking for a quick answer. Some patient guidance that will (hopefully) see me complete this assignment and understand more would be much appreciated. I also apologize if this exercise is incredibly simple for some. I am very VERY new to the c# language and programming in general.

Below is the code I have so far. As you can see, I have structured it so I can follow along with my own work without getting lost. I feel like a toddler but hey, dumbing things down seems to be the only way I can really get a handle on any of this stuff. I may not be a natural at programming but by god I wont give up!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assessment2_Nicole_Haines

{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            card PlayerCard = new card(6,26); // Calls an instance of the card struct to create PlayerCard card

card PlayerCard2 = new card(6,26); // Calls an instance of the card struct to create PlayerCard2 card
            card PlayerCard3 = new card(6,26); // Calls an instance of the card struct to create PlayerCard3 card

            card DealerCard = new card(6,26); // Calls a new instance of the struct (named card) to create the dealers card with 2 numbers

            //declare an array of card
            card[] PlayerCards = { PlayerCard, PlayerCard2, PlayerCard3 };

            // Welcome text
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome! Press the 'enter' key to play!");
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Use of struct for Dealers single card
            Console.WriteLine("The dealers card is: {0} , {1}", DealerCard.Number1, DealerCard.Number2);  
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Use of struct for Players first card
            Console.WriteLine("Your first card is: {0} , {1}", PlayerCard.Number1, PlayerCard.Number2);  
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Use of struct for Players second card
            Console.WriteLine("Your second card is: {0} , {1}", PlayerCard2.Number1, PlayerCard2.Number2);
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Use of struct for Players third (and final) card
            Console.WriteLine("Your third (and final!) card is: {0}, {1}", PlayerCard3.Number1, PlayerCard3.Number2);
            Console.ReadLine();

            // Request user input - As you can see - the rest of the code is incomplete/incorrect

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number you wish to 'play' in order to beat the dealer:"); 


                // Accept/Parse user input 
// Create a while loop that runs application again if user enters Y. otherwise - exits.




            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to play again?");
            Console.ReadLine(); 



            Console.WriteLine("You selected 'Y' Let's play again!");
            Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("You selected 'N' See you later!");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        // Struct

        public struct card
        {

            static Random r = new Random();
            public int Number1;
            public int Number2;
            public card(int Minimum, int Maximum)
            {
                Number1 = r.Next(Minimum, Maximum);
                Number2 = r.Next(Minimum, Maximum);
            }

        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer is very simple heres a link that will help
http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readkey

```
   // Call ReadKey again and test for the letter Y.
info = Console.ReadKey();
if (info.KeyChar == 'Y')
{
    Play again;
}

  // Call ReadKey again and test for the letter Y.
info = Console.ReadKey();
if (info.KeyChar == 'N')
{
   Close;
}
```

Also I think your if statement,

```
  if (PlayerSelection > DealerCard) 
   { 
Console.WriteLine ("You Win");
    }
  else if(DealerCard > PlayerSelection) 
  { 
Console.WriteLine ("Dealer Wins");
  }
 else if (PlayerSelection == DealerCard)
  { 
Console.WriteLine ("It is a draw");
  }
  else{Console.WriteLine("Something Went Wrong"}
```

As far as determining who wins with the tryparse,

```
   // Call ReadKey again and test for the letter Y.
info = Console.ReadLine();
    int pleayercardvalue = tryparse(info, int32)
if (playercardvalue != playercard1.value OR playercard2.value OR playercard3.value)
{
    "Select Valid Card";
}
    else
    {
      playercardvalue
    }
```

None of these are exact code, just the rough idea.

Comment: Thank you. Being a learner I did not even know that the ReadKey method even exists. This is extremely handy to know. Unfortunately the assessment does require the use of a while loop to rerun or exit the application. I have made a note of ReadKey though, that will definitely come in handy with my own experimentation of c# language features.

Comment: Im reasonably sure you will use the readkey method to set the while loop. After all you have to know if they select Y or N.

Answer (score 0):

Most types in C# have two methods for parsing strings into values of that type, `Parse` and `TryParse`. The syntax for calling both is the same.  The `TryParse` method differs from the `Parse` method in that `TryParse` returns a `bool` that indicates whether the string was parsed or not.  That is, passing "1" to `int.TryParse` will return true, but passing "A" will return false.

These methods are overloaded.  The easiest one to call is `TryParse(string)`, which just takes the string to be parsed as its only argument.  It will use the application's current Culture settings, whatever that is, to parse the number.  This is probably OK, because the default Culture is the same as that specified in the Windows culture settings.  Other overloads allow you to specify specific culture and formatting options.  Don't worry about those.

Lastly, your loop.  You would put your code inside of a loop, I'd use a `do . . . while` loop, that first does everything you're doing now, determines the winner, then asks the user if they want to play again.  Parse their response (this isn't a call to `TryParse`, but comparing their response to the expected response), and if they say yes, the loop repeats.